# «вИпробування» чи «випрОбування»?

Tags: наголос

Де правильно поставити наголос: «вИпробування» чи «випрОбування»? В орфографічних словниках зустрічала обидва варіанти. Є різниця між цими варіантами? Чи це слово має подвійний наголос?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Сучасний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index) каже, що «[випр**о́**бування](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10227&page=348)» — це дія за значенням «випробовувати» **і також «знегоди, великі труднощі, лихо»**, а «[в**и́**пробування](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10226&page=348)» — це **лише** дія за значенням «випробовувати» <sub>(точніше, він каже, не «дія за значенням „випробовувати“», а «дія за значенням „випр**о́**бувати“» і «дія за значенням „в**и́**пробувати“» відповідно — але і «[випр**о́**бувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10229&page=348)», і «[в**и́**пробувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10228&page=348)» у цьому словнику подаються як форми від «випроб***о́*ву**вати»).</sub>

Але наголоси — то дуже гнучкий і чи не найменш формалізований аспект мови. Вони швидко змінюються і дуже варіюють за діалектами. Тому я не впевнений, що можна на 100% довіряти цьому словнику (як і будь-яким словникам).

Answer (score 1):

Якщо чесно, я не дуже зрозумів [відповідь](/a/2955/585) пана [@Sasha](/users/4/sasha) і здивувався тому, що вона затвердженна. Спробував розібратись самому, бо також здивувала така собі „неповага“ до наголосів. Також не буде зайвим вказати: це один з результатів [совітизації](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n35texts/kocherha.htm), що робить складні і нерозумні речі: засилля наростків *‑ува‑*.

---

*В**и́**пробування* → *ви́пробувати* — **доконаниь вид**. *Чудове ви́пробування* — головне: результат.

*Випр**о́**бування* → *випро́бувати*, инша форма (наразі не так важливо) *випробо́вувати* — **недоконаниь вид**. *Чудове випро́бування* — головне: процес. Слово цілком замінюється на [випроб](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10217&page=348).

---

Наголоси — головна річ мови і не змінюється „як завгодно“ чи аби-як. Для прикладу покажу ось таку частину.

[Норми української літературної мови](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo), 1914 •
[Олекса Синявський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> ### 7. Словозміна: дієслово
>
> #### § 84. Недоконаність – доконаність
>
> *[…]*
>   розкида́ти, розкида́ю... – розки́дати, розки́даю...
>   перетика́ти, перетика́ю... – перети́кати, перети́каю...
>   задиха́тися, задиха́юся... – зади́хатися, зади́хаюся...
>   вистриба́ти, вистриба́ю... – ви́стрибати, ви́стрибаю...
>   вистина́ти, вистина́ю... – ви́стинати, ви́стинаю...
>   збіга́ти, збіга́ю... – збі́гати, збі́гаю...
>   здиба́тися, здиба́юся... – зди́батися, зди́баюся...
>   підслуха́ти, підслуха́ю... – підслу́хати, підслу́хаю...
>   виміря́ти, виміря́ю... – ви́міряти, ви́міряю...
>   наставля́ти, наставля́ю... – наста́вляти, наста́вляю...
>   виліта́ти, виліта́ю... – ви́літати, ви́літаю...
>   виганя́ти, виганя́ю... – ви́ганяти, ви́ганяю...
>   насипа́ти, насипа́ю... – наси́пати, наси́плю...
>   витяга́ти, витяга́ю... – ви́тягати, ви́тягаю...
>   намика́ти, намика́ю... – нами́кати, нами́каю...
>   насмика́ти, насмика́ю... – насми́кати, насми́каю... (і насми́чу)
>   виклика́ти, виклика́в... – ви́кликати, ви́кликав...
>   вила́зити, вила́зив... – ви́лазити, ви́лазив...
>   проїзди́ти, проїзди́в... – прої́здити, прої́здив...

Comment: Так, Ви праві щодо дієслів — я якось відразу не збагнув, що «ви́пробувати» доконане, а «випро́бувати» (мабуть, повний еквівалент до більш вживаного «випробо́вувати») завжди недоконане. Але це, як на мене, не пояснює різницю в значенні (чи її відсутність, на Вашу думку?) між іменниками.

Comment: «Головне: результат <…> головне: процес» — Ви впевнені? (У випадку, наприклад, «відчуття» і «відчування», мабуть, так — але для «ви́пробування»/«випро́бування» я не впевнений, що різниця настільки очевидна.)

Comment: Ну, наприклад, результат випробування (процесу) не позначається одним словом «ви́пробування». Хоча результат бачення (процесу) ми можемо позначати одним словом «бачення» («його бачення»), результат відчування/відчуття (процесу) — одним лише словом «відчуття», результат заробітку/заробляння (процесу) — «заробіток» (гроші), результат праці (процесу) — «праця» (книга), результат творіння — «твір»/«творіння». Натомість ми результат випробування позначаємо «результат випробування» — здається слово «випробування» взагалі не має відтінку результату (незалежно від наголосу).

Comment: «До того ж: ви́пробуваний… випро́буваний…» — у випадку дієприкметників я згоден, як і у випадку дієслів. А от у випадку іменників мені здається, не все так прямолінійно, на жаль.

Comment: Як «результат випробування» назвати? «Випроб»=«випро́бування» — це ж процес…

Comment: То Ви можете прямим текстом сказати — як матеріалізований результат випробування (визначені під час випробування характеристики) назвати? (Бо я коментар перечитав, але щоби з нього випливала відповідь на це — не бачу.) (До речі, «ви́проб» і «ви́проба» вже не вписуються в схему з наголосами, бо наголос на «и», а за словником «ви́проб»=«ви́проба»=«випро́бування».)

Comment: Тобто, може, Ви й праві, але я Вашу думку про процес і результат не розумію. В моєму розумінні і «ви́пробування», і «випро́бування» — процес, а результат одним словом не позначається.

Comment: Будь ласка, дайте спочатку відповідь на запитання, яке я першим поставив: як Ви називатимете матеріалізований результат випробування (тобто визначені під час випробування характеристики) — невже словом «ви́пробування»?

Comment: Тобто визначені під час випро́бування характеристики (або папірець чи файл з ними) Ви можете назвати словом «ви́пробування»? Якось так: «Де ви́пробування?» — «А ось там на столі лежить». Чи все-таки ні?

Comment: Тоді нема питань. Отже в нас дуже різне значення змісту слова «ви́пробування». (А що Ви скажете на те, що «ви́проб(а)» має наголос на першому складі, хоч це процес?)