# В чім різниця між "передобробка" і "передобробл(е/я)ння"?

Tags: віддієслівні-іменники, іменники

Яке слово правильно вжити тут, якщо мова йде про тривалий в часі процес:

> Алгоритм потребує певний час на *передобробку/передобробл(е/я)ння*.

Знайшов оцю дискусію - [Оброблення даних чи обробка даних?](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1128202726.html), але ще не певен, як правильно. Витяг зі згаданої сторінки з відповіді Сергія Вакуленко:

> Скільки пам'ятаю, ОБРОБКА — це усталений ще з совкових часів варіянт
>   (узорований на рос. ОБРАБОТКА).
>
> Для української мови природнішими є слова на -ННЯ або -ТТЯ.
>
> Серед иншого вони дають змогу перенести в похідні іменники дієслівне
>   розрізнення видів:
>
> недоконаний: обробляти > обробляння
>
> доконаний: обробити > оброблення
>
> Фахівці, які творять сучасну українську термінологію, дотримуються
>   думки, що то є надзвичайно важливе термінологічне розрізнення
>   (перебіг/наслідок).
>
> А втім, дорікнути Вам ніхто не зможе, навіть якщо Ви напишете ОБРОБКА
>   (бо ж словник так каже...).

Comment: Принаймні, Кочерга і Мейнарович подають *[preprocessing](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=preprocessing&dicts=all)* як `передобробля́ння//‌передобро́блення, передобробі́ток, попере́днє [перви́нне, підгото́вче] обробля́ння//‌обро́блення, попере́дній [перви́нний, підгото́вчий] обробі́ток`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Спрощений погляд

З мого погляду, як росифікованого українця…

Обробка — (1) дія; (2) результат дії.

Оброблення — дія.

Обробляння — дія з конотацією неодноразовості/повторюваності.

Відповідно:

- «Алгоритм потребує певного часу / певний час на передобробку» — прийнятно¹.
- «Алгоритм потребує певного часу / певний час на передоброблення» — правильно.
- «Алгоритм потребує певного часу / певний час на передобробляння» — лише у випадку, коли алгоритм (протягом одного запуску) виконує передоброблення неодноразово (наприклад, містить цикл, на кожній ітерації якого відбувається передоброблення).

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах більш-менш підтверджує мою позицію, хоча про конотацію повторюваності/неодноразовості слова «передобробляння» не каже².

<sub>¹ Хоча, напевно, певна кількість людей будуть незадоволені таким ужитком.

² Точніше, він каже, що «оброблення» — дія за значенням «обробити» (доконане дієслово), а обробляння — дія за значенням «обробляти» (недоконане дієслово), але, як на мене, це ні про що (тим більше, що «обробка» — знов за «обробляти» (недоконане дієслово)).</sub>

<sub>P. S.: Зверніть увагу: на `sum.in.ua` в означеннях цих слів є одруки, через які може скластися враження, начебто «обробка» відсилає до інших значень слова «обробляти/обробити» (дія до 2-го, а результат — до 1-го/3-го), ніж «оброблення» і «обробляння» (1-ше)  — але це просто помилка сканування.</sub>

## Заглиблений погляд

Частина мовознавців кажуть, що слова можуть позначати не «дію/подію» і «результат/наслідок», а є аж три категорії: «дія», «подія» і «результат/наслідок».

А деякі мовознавці кажуть про ще більшу кількість категорій (частково втрачених).

Я особисто **не розумію цього**, але наведу посилання, за якими хтось, можливо, зможе розібратися.

#### Де згадуються три категорії: «дія», «подія» і «результат/наслідок»

- [Чи є різниця між словами зіставляння і зіставлення](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1202)
- [«вИпробування» чи «випрОбування»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2951)
- [Як правильно "скористУйтесь" чи "скористАйтесь"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3017) і [Різниця між словами скористатися/скористуватися?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4037)
- ["Одиниця вимірювання" чи "одиниця виміру"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3106)
- [УклАдення чи укладАння договору?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3744)
- [Як правильно, акт звірки чи звіряння?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4157)

#### Де згадується більше трьох категорій

Олекса Синявський, [«Норми української літературної мови»](//r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8,%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(1941).pdf), а саме — [розділ 7 «Словозміна. Дієслово»](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo), § 83 «Видові форми дієслів. Вступні зауваги»:

> Усіх форм тривання (видів) в українськім дієслові досить багато, але вони не сталі: в одних дієсловах їх більше, в інших менше. Основними, давно вже відміченими розрядами тривання дієслів, а саме недоконаними й доконаними, далеко не вичерпуються форми тривання нашого дієслова взагалі, як не вичерпуються вони й ще одним поділом на форми протяжні та наворотні. Є поодинокі дієслова, що в них можна вирізнити **до 10 відтінків** тривання…

Різні фрагменти цієї роботи, стосовні цієї теми, цитуються тут: [Суфікс дієслів ‑ува‑ чи що таке протяжні, наворотні?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4049)